# gcc warning of "variable set but not used" using different constructor initializer lists

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, warnings, initializer-list

In C++ is possible to define a variable x of a class X that has constructors that require arguments, using different notations:

```
X x{...};      // modern style (1)  
X x = {...};   // slightly more verbose modern style (2)  
X x = X{...};  // verbose modern style (3)
X x(...);      // old '98 style (4)
X x = X(...);  // verbose old '98 style (5)
```

If the object x is not subsequently used gcc issues the warning:

```
variable ‘x’ set but not used
```

only in cases (2),(3) and (5) where the = is used, but not in cases (1) and (4).
Shouldn't the warning be issued also in those cases?

I'm using gcc version 6.1.1 20160511 with *-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++14* under Linux

I tried for further investigation also the clang compiler. Interestingly, clang issues the warning only for cases (3) and (5) but not for the others. See https://godbolt.org/g/qW712c

I also tried to compare the assembly output of the 5 different versions. The assembly code is byte to byte identical for all the 5 versions and this is true both for gcc and clang.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce (1)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5564a34842148d15) (different warning message, but w/e); (4) is a function declaration.

Comment: I wrongly omitted dots for indicating the presence of arguments between braces, edited. I can reproduce (1): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32bc35e547853868

Comment: I can only imagine that it's so that stuff like `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(mutex);` (or any other guard-like construct) doesn't emit a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor might have side effect.
If that is the case unused variable shouldn't be an error. Compiler can't possibly know if constructor have side effect, so it won't produce errors.

2, 3, 5 are different because they are construction and assignment.

Comment: But does this mean that in 2, 3, 5 there is the construction of a temporary object and then this temporary object is copied in x, while in 1 and 4, x is directly constructed?

Comment: I don't think copy actually happens but semantically assaignment is there and g++ issue warning to unused 'assigned' variable (-Wunused-but-set-variable).